# Generating xml graphs using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using POI to create a report in xls format. Then I enhanced it to show graphs for the data in report. As per the limitation of POI, it cannot create graphs in excel. So, I am using a template and rewriting data in it everytime and the graph gets refreshed.

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(columnsArray[j1]);
cell.setCellValue(Integer.valueOf(count));
```

Bad practice, but I have to hardcode the position of cells in an array.

```
int columnsArray[] = {
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
};
```

Anyone using a better approach or any other alternative of POI which could achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
GV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till now as the [apache POI limitation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html) is saying **"You can not currently create charts. You can however create a chart in Excel, modify the chart data values using HSSF and write a new spreadsheet out. This is possible because POI attempts to keep existing records intact as far as possible".**

However in the same case, I have created a chart manually on excel sheet using Named Ranges and using java, I am updating named ranges as per my requirement. Since the chart is based on named ranges so it also get updated.

you can update the existing Reference of named ranges and set it as per your requirement. 
Suppose the reference contains `MySheet!$A$1:$B$8`and you want to change it to  `MySheet!$B$5:$C$12`

For any cell, say "B5", at runtime,

```
cell.getReference();
```

will give you cell reference (like in example... it will return you "B5")

```
char startCellColRef = cell.getReference().toString().charAt(0);
```

will give you the Column Reference (will give you "B" if the current cell is B5). Now

```
int startCellRowRef = cell.getReference().toString().charAt(1);
```

will give you Row Index (will give you "5" if the current cell is B5).

By the same way you can get your start and end cell references (say B5 and C12).

Now comes how can I update the existing references. Just update its value with newly created reference string

```
Name reference = wb.getName("NameReferenceInExcelSheet");
referenceString = sheetName+"!$"+startCellColRef+"$"+startCellRowRef+":$"+endCellColRef+"$"+endCellRowRef;
reference.setRefersToFormula(referenceString);
```

By this way you just need to create name ranges manually and then graph/chart that you want manually based on Named ranges, and then you need to update the named ranges... Since the chart/graph is based on that, it will get updated automatically.

Comment: I got most of the answer but a bit confused on the last part. Suppose my chart is based on B5 through B10. When the program updates data, it reflects in chart. But what if want to change the range e.g from B5 through B15. Can I do it via java or it has to be done manually?

Comment: You can change the ranges as well. If initially chart is based on the data of B5 to B10 and now it is based on B5 to B15, you can change the name range values, and the chart will get updated accordingly. Just for understanding you can think NamedRanges are variables representing the range of data. Chart is based on this variable. So any change in variable value will reflect in chart and you can change the variable value by program as well.

Comment: Let me give it a try. That could really serve my purpose. Thanks for your inputs.. Much appreciated.